# How to enable copy-pasting in VirtualBox command line with FreeBSD

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, freebsd

I have FreeBSD 12.2 installed on VirtualBox 6.1. When I try to copy a text from Notepad++ editor and paste it to the VirtualBox command line by right-clicking, I receive the window about mouse capturing and if I enable the capturing, I don't see the cursor anymore.

I have "Bidirectional" option enabled and "Guest Additions" installed.

How to enable and use copy-pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the problem by SSH via Putty.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1068803)

Comment: This DOES provide the answer as there is no another way to enable copy-pasting in the case of VirtualBox. If you still know about a way, please leave at least a comment about.

Comment: Use the EDIT button to add the pertinent details, fleshing this out. You are not answering the question for yourself here, you are helping others who may have the same problem in the future. As such, your answer needs to be a complete thought and needs to contain such information as will make someone else be able to say "that answers my question". Until it does that, it is not an answer